# The entity type 'List<string>' requires a primary key to be defined in my mstest

Tags: c#, .net, mstest

While making some unit tests with mstest this error showed up when I set up `UseInMemoryDatabase`. Important is that the error does not show up when I run the app. Only when running a test. It seems to come from here:

```
public List<string> WordProgress { get; set; } = new List<string>();
```

The error is gone when I add [NotMapped] above, but this makes the column dissapear.

Context:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<FinalWord>()
        .HasMany(c => c.Games)
        .WithOne(e => e.FinalWord);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Game>()
        .HasMany(c => c.GameWords)
        .WithOne(e => e.Game);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Game>()
        .HasOne(c => c.FinalWord)
        .WithMany(e => e.Games);
    
    modelBuilder.Entity<Word>()
        .HasMany(c => c.GameWords)
        .WithOne(e => e.Word);

    modelBuilder.Entity<GameWord>()
        .HasOne(c => c.Game)
        .WithMany(e => e.GameWords);
    
    modelBuilder.Entity<GameWord>()
        .HasOne(c => c.Word)
        .WithMany(e => e.GameWords);
}
```

GameWord.cs

```
    public class GameWord
{
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public List<string> WordProgress { get; set; } = new List<string>();
  
  [Required]
  public Word Word { get; set; }
  [Required]
  public Game Game { get; set; }
  public bool Finished { get; set; } = false;
}
```

And my test setup.

```
    public UnitTest1()
{
    DbContextOptionsBuilder<LingoContext> dbOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<LingoContext>()
        .UseInMemoryDatabase(
            Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
        );
        
    _context = new LingoContext(dbOptions.Options);
}

    [TestMethod]
public void GetAllGames()
{
    var repo = new SqlGameRepo(_context);
    Game game1 = new Game();
    Game game2 = new Game();
    _context.Game.Add(game1);
    _context.Game.Add(game2);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    
    IEnumerable<Game> result = repo.GetAllGames();
    
    Assert.AreEqual(result.Count(), 2);
}
```

Anyone knows the reason why?

Comment: It's treating the `List<String>` as a navigation property, e.g. it expects there to be a table of `string` which it can join to the `GameWord` table. When you deploy this to production, how do you expect `WordProgress` to be saved to the database?

Comment: So adding a new table for wordProgress should fix this? I was hoping I could just save a list of strings in one column. It has nothing in common with other tables so it seems to me a bit useless to create a separate table.

Comment: Are you going to be using a relational database, e.g. SQL, when you deploy this in production? Relational databases do not support a column being a 'list' - you have to create a separate table and use a foreign key and a join, _or_ map the column to a different type e.g. convert the values to a comma-separated string or a json string

Comment: Thanks for your help Andrew. I created a simple new table with foreign key. Works perfect! Maybe next time I could save it into a different data type instead of list. The new table feels a bit overkill when it is basically a one to one relationship. But I am okay with the solution!

Comment: You're welcome! I've written up the info from the comments into an answer, and provided some examples of the alternative solutions for you to look at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity Framework is treating the `List<String>` as a navigation property, e.g. it expects there to be a table of `string` which it can join to the GameWord table.

Relational databases do not support a column being a 'list' - you have to create a separate table and use a foreign key and a join, or map the column to a different type e.g. convert the values to a comma-separated string or a json string

As a separate table:

```cs
public class GameWord
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<Attempt> WordProgress { get; set; } = new List<Attempt>();

    [Required]
    public Word Word { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Game Game { get; set; }
    public bool Finished { get; set; } = false;
}

public class Attempt
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int GameWordId { get; set; }
    public GameWord GameWord { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

As a comma-separated string:

```cs
// The Entity that you have defined doesn't need to be changed
public class GameWord
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<Attempt> WordProgress { get; set; } = new List<Attempt>();

    [Required]
    public Word Word { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Game Game { get; set; }
    public bool Finished { get; set; } = false;
}

// Just specify how to convert the C# property to the SQL value
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<GameWord>()
        .Property(c => c.WordProgress)
        .HasConversion(
            attempts => string.Join(",", attempts),
            csv => csv.Split(',')
        );
}
```

As json:

```cs
// Specify a different conversion
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<GameWord>()
        .Property(c => c.WordProgress)
        .HasConversion(
            attempts => JsonSerializer.Serialize(attempts, (JsonSerializerOptions)null),
            json => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<string>>(json, (JsonSerializerOptions)null)
        );
}
```

---

When you see how easy it is to add a json or csv column to a table with Entity Framework, you might think the first approach of adding a whole new table is overkill. I would still recommend starting with that approach, and only switch to a custom conversion if performance is affected by the join operation (which I think is unlikely here). The reasons being:

- Navigation properties with an ORM are common and easy for devs to understand. Custom conversions are not. They are a specific feature of Entity Framework Core, and there are some subtleties in how a conversion affects the change tracking done by EF
- If you decide in the future that you want to store more than just a single 'word' value, maybe the 'word' and the time at which the attempt was made, you have to write a funky migration script to unpack the values in the column and convert them to a different format. With a dedicated entity type and child table, you can just add a new column.
- Entity Framework usually can't translate SQL filter operations on a converted column. If you want to search for all games where the player has attempted the word 'Fruit', you would have to write the SQL yourself. If you use a child table and navigation properties, this is simple to write:

```cs
context.GameWords.Where(
    gameWord => gameWord.WordProgress.Any(
        attempt => attempt.Value == "Fruit"
    )
)
```